# How to prevent auto adding of action and method attributes into form element in ASP.NET MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

Using *ASP.NET MVC 6 with Angular JS* and following code

```
<form name="mainForm" ng-submit="sendForm('/Home/Register4')" asp-anti-forgery="false" novalidate>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
        Send
    </button>
</form>
```

appears like the code below in browser *(Chrome)*

```
<form name="mainForm" ng-submit="sendForm('/Home/Register4')" action="/Home/Index4" method="post">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
        Send
    </button>
</form>
```

is there any specific keyword that prevents adding **action** and **method** attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is fixed in nightly MVC 6 builds. See [aspnet/Mvc#2606](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2606) or the earlier [aspnet/Mvc#2581](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2581) for more information. As mentioned there, the workaround in earlier releases is to add an exclamation mark to the element name e.g. `<!form>...`.

Answer (score 2):

Im guessing you will get your desired behavior by removing the asp-anti-forgery attribute, since that attribute forces the form-tag to be rendered by the FormTagHelper.

Edit: Looking at the source at https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers/FormTagHelper.cs it seems the tag helper doesen't touch forms that already have an action attribute. What if you put an empty action attribute on your form?

Then it will by defalt post to the current page. If that doesen't work I would report a bug on GitHub. I can see lots of cases where a form without an action could be useful...

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work.  Plus, if I remove that, it will add AntiForgeryToken into the form.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, as you guessed, I do not want any action at all.  Unfortunately it keeps adding it

Comment: As a workaround until the bug is fixed you could write your own FormTagHelper and remove the action attribute. I believe you can control ordering of the helpers with the [Order](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.Runtime/TagHelpers/TagHelper.cs#L15) property so your TagHelper always run after the built in one.

Comment: Andreas, thank you for your effort again!  I voted up your answer.